# TypeError while compiling Keras model with custom loss function

Tags: python, keras, image-segmentation, loss-function, pre-trained-model

I have trained a model with custom loss function BinaryCrossEntropy, with Jaccard, using segmentation models library, when I tried to load and compile the model in order to start prediction, I have got this Error:
`model = compile(optimizer='adam', loss=bce_jaccard_loss, metrics=['iou_score'])
TypeError: compile() missing required argument 'source' (pos 1)`

How can I solve that please?

```
import keras
import segmentation_models as sm
from segmentation_models.losses import bce_jaccard_loss
from segmentation_models.metrics import iou_score

model = keras.models.load_model("ResNet_34_Aug.h5", compile = False)
model = compile(optimizer='adam', loss=bce_jaccard_loss, metrics=['iou_score'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole problem was on the last line of the code, the missing required argument 'source' (pos 1) is the model itself, so I have fixed that to:

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=bce_jaccard_loss, metrics=['iou_score'])
```